# Behavior of $n^\alpha \sin^{\circ\, n}(n^{-\alpha}x)$

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems, limits-and-convergence

I'll write it formally: Let $\sin^{\circ\, 1}(x) = \sin(x)$ and $\sin^{\circ n+1}(x) = \sin\bigl(\sin^{\circ n}(x)\bigr)$ for $n\in \Bbb N$ with $n>1$.
What is the limit as $n \to \infty$?

It's fairly easy to prove that the absolute value of $f(n,x)$ is decreasing for every constant $x$ as $n$ is increasing, so the limit exists. From what I calculated, it seems like $f(\infty,x)= 0$ for all $x$. Does someone have a proof for that?

---

*Follow up:* The limit $\sin^{\circ n}(x)\rightarrow 0$ may be a bit trivial. What if we rescale $x$ and ask for the limit of $$n^\alpha \sin^{\circ n}(n^{-\alpha}x)$$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$? For which $\alpha$ does the limit exist and what is it?

Comment: If the limit exists it must be a fixed point if the sine.

Comment: And the limit exists since $\sin(x) \in [-1,1]$ and on $[-1,1]$ you have that $\sin x$ and $x$ have the same sign, while $|\sin x| \leq x$. So the generated sequence is eventually monotone.

Comment: to make this question less trivial and more appropriate for MO, I have added the rescaled limit as a follow-up question; perhaps if it's reopened the limit for $\alpha\neq 0,1/2$ can be considered in an answer.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3837335/proving-the-limiting-behavior-of-functions-containing-iterated-trigonometric-fun for the square root case and links to other topics related to the sine iteration.

Comment: cosine converges at non-zero

Answer (score 33):

A rescaling is needed for a nontrivial limit. As discussed in [Iteration of Sine and Related Power Series](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/math.mag.87.5.338#metadata_info_tab_contents) by C. Towse (2014), denoting the $n$-th iterate by $\sin^{\circ n}x$, one has the limit
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt n\sin^{\circ n}(x/\sqrt n)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2/3}}.$$
The graph (from the cited paper) shows that the limit is attained quite rapidly.
[image]

Without the rescaling the iterated sine converges to zero (for the reasons indicated in the comments to the OP). The convergence is slow, see the graph.

[image]

---

For the general rescaling,
$$z_\alpha(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n^\alpha\sin^{\circ n}(n^{-\alpha}x),$$
I surmise (based on the small-$x$ expansion of the sine$^\ast$) that the limit is $z_\alpha(x)=0$ for $\alpha<1/2$ and $z_\alpha(x)=x$ for $\alpha>1/2$. This agrees quite well with the numerics, see plots below

[image][image]

Plots of $n^\alpha\sin^{\circ n}(n^{-\alpha}x)$ for $n=500$ and $\alpha=0.75$ (left) and $\alpha=0.25$ (right). The horizontal lines in the right plot show the asymptote $(\text{sign}\,x)\,\sqrt{3}\,n^{\alpha-1/2}$.

---

$^\ast$ For $\alpha<1/2$ we can proceed as follows: Assume a power law decay, $y_n=(\text{sign}\,x)\,n^\alpha\sin^{\circ n}(n^{-\alpha}x)=(\text{sign}\,x)cn^{-p}$, substitute into $y_{n+1}=(n+1)^\alpha \sin(y_n/n^\alpha)$, and expand for large $n$. So we have
$$c(n+1)^{-p}\approx cn^{-p}-cpn^{-p-1},\;\; (n+1)^\alpha\sin(cn^{-p-\alpha})\approx cn^{-p}+\alpha cn^{-p-1}-\tfrac{1}{6}c^3n^{-3p-2\alpha},$$
and equating these two expressions gives $p=\tfrac{1}{2}-\alpha$, $c=\sqrt{6(p+\alpha)}=\sqrt{3}$. We thus arrive at the large-$n$ asymptotics
$$n^\alpha\sin^{\circ n}(n^{-\alpha}x)\rightarrow (\text{sign}\,x)\,\sqrt{3}\,n^{\alpha-1/2}\rightarrow 0,\;\;\text{for}\;\;\alpha<1/2.$$

Comment: At first I had some misgivings about one changing a question and then answering it, but looking up the paper I can see that in this case it is both justified and interesting.

Comment: $$x-\frac{x^3}{6}<\sin(x)<x$$ for $x>0$, so $$\sin^{ck}(x)-\frac16 (\sin^{ck}(x))^3 < \sin^{c(k+1)}(x) < \sin^{ck}(x),$$ which in turn yields 
$$
\sin^{ck}(x)-\frac{x^3}{6}<\sin^{c(k+)1}(x)<x, \textrm{ and }   x-n\frac{x^3}{6}<\sin^{cn}(x)<x
$$
So writing $v_n= n^\alpha \sin^{cn}\left(n^{-\alpha}x\right)$, we have 
$$
x- n^{1-2\alpha} \frac{x^3}{6} < v_n(x) < x
$$
So when $\alpha > \frac12$, $v_n\to x$.

Comment: @Yaakov, you were not the only one with misgivings.  See https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5150/to-which-extent-can-one-modify-anothers-question where the question